# The app closes instantly when launching from custom scheme url - flutter - uni_links

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm using custom scheme and am testing
on my iPhone6, iOS Simulator
which is running iOS 15

the app works fine when I launch it from https (Universal Link)
but when I try to launch it using Custom URL scheme it crashes instantly, dosent reach the main function ether.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure you'll need to register your schemes here if I answered your question;

I have some examples below.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>https</string>
        <string>http</string>
        <string>mailto</string>
        <string>tel</string>
        <string>facetime</string>
        <string>sms</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: still the app not launching. instantly get closed.